Creating multiple pie/bar charts from pd.dataframe, finding column with max and min values
My dataframe looks like this, and i'm now looking for appropriate analysis techniques, i'm hoping some people on here could give me some advice on either creating graphs from this dataframe, or pulling 'max' and 'min'.



Site
A
B
C
D




Blue
4
13
9
11


Green
1
12
30
20


Yellow
12
2
3
3


Red
20
14
4
0



I first want to make pie charts for each site depicting ratios or bar charts for each site,
and then to write code which allows outputs the site with max and min 'Blue', 'Green' etc     frequencies
I have tried: p = df[["C"]].value_counts(sort="False").plot(kind='bar')
to no effect, and have played around with this, but i'm not sure how to reference the colour values  where '1' is.
x_axis = df.iloc[1].values
y_axis = df.iloc[1].values
plt.bar(x_axis,y_axis,color = 'b')
plt.xlabel('Site')
plt.ylabel('Colour')
plt.show()


You can do all these plots in a single go:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Site': ['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'],
    'A': [4, 1, 12, 20],
    'B': [13, 12, 2, 14],
    'C': [9, 30, 3, 4],
    'D': [11, 20, 3, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('Site', inplace=True)

def create_plots_grid(df):
    sites = df.index
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(sites), ncols=2, figsize=(12, 12))

    for i, site in enumerate(sites):
        data = df.loc[site]
        
        data.plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, ax=axes[i, 0])
        axes[i, 0].set_ylabel('')
        axes[i, 0].set_title(f'Pie Chart for {site} Site')
        
        data.plot.bar(ax=axes[i, 1])
        axes[i, 1].set_title(f'Bar Chart for {site} Site')
        axes[i, 1].set_xlabel('Category')
        axes[i, 1].set_ylabel('Value')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

create_plots_grid(df)

max_sites = df.idxmax()
min_sites = df.idxmin()

print("Site with maximum values for each column:")
print(max_sites)

print("\nSite with minimum values for each column:")
print(min_sites)

which gives

and
Site with maximum values for each column:
A      Red
B      Red
C    Green
D    Green
dtype: object

Site with minimum values for each column:
A     Green
B    Yellow
C    Yellow
D       Red
dtype: object


Thank you so much! I can't wait to try it out!
